# JdbcTemplate multiple variables in query

Tags: java, variables, bind, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to run a query like the one below

```
select col1 from table1 where col2 = ? and col3 = ?
```

I would like to use JdbcTemplate

can I write like this?

```
String query = new String("select col1 from table1 where col2 = ? and col3 = ?");
Object[] parameters = new Object[] {new String(col2), new String(col3)};

Object module = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, parameters,"");


**Object module = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, parameters,String.class);** is this right?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JdbcTemplate` has several overloaded versions of that method.  Which one do you intend to call?

You can add in a `RowMapper` implementation for the object type you're interested in.  That's what I'd recommend.

```
public class YourRowMapper implements RowMapper<YourClass> {
    YourClass mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        return new YourClass();  // map the ResultSet row here.
    }
}
```

Comment: No, read the javadocs.  A little effort on your part Anand, please.